# What is the expected number of points in an exam

Tags: probability

There are $15$ questions:

- $10$ true/false questions, worth $2$ points each, you get $0$ points with a probability of $1/4$ and $2$ points with a probability of $3/4$
- $4$ questions, worth $15$ points each, get points equal to the sum of two dice throws plus $3$ points
- Last is worth $20$ points, get either $12$ or $18$ points with the same probability.

All random choices are independent from each other.

I've written down the possible number of points but I'm having trouble determining what's most likely

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I've written down the possible number of points but I'm having trouble determining what's most likely. I'm having trouble understanding it, like if I get 2 points with a probability of 3/4, then shouldn't I expect to get full points in 10 questions?

Comment: For first part the expected number of points is $0 * (1/4)+ 2*(3/4)$.  Does that help?

Comment: @user121049 so the expected number of points from the true/false would be 15? But it isn't possible to get 15p since it's not a multiplicative of 2. Or am I missing something,.. And the second part, do I have to write out all the different possible points and then check which one is the most common? The last one is 50/50 so I shouldn't both be expected

Comment: For one, what is most likely and expected number of points is different. "Expectation" is the average number of points over all scenarios. "Most likely" is finding the distribution of points over all possible points [0,100], and finding which point is most probable. Since these are independent, expectation is simple, just sum the expectation of each part.

Comment: Expectation doesn't need to be a possible solution. If you have a 50% chance of getting 1 and a 50% chance of getting 0, the expectation is 0.5.